# How to add ppa entries manually on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, apt, aptitude

I would like to know how I can add a "ppa" entry manually on the Raspberry Pi for the "apt" program.

Where should I add my "ppa" entry (in which file) ?

For example, I want to add the following ppa entry for guvcview.

```
ppa:pj-assis/ppa
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways:

- Go to the [PPA's web page](https://launchpad.net/~pj-assis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), click on "Technical details about this PPA" and copy paste those lines into your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or create a new file at e.g. `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pj-assis-ppa.list` with these lines as contents. Figuring out which Ubuntu version (for replacing `YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE`) fits best to your Raspbian can be done by trial and error. It bascially depends on the Raspbian version you're using and the available Ubuntu versions in the PPA. For Raspbian Jessie, `vivid` (if still available) is usually best fitting.
- Install the package [software-properties-common](https://packages.debian.org/software-properties-common), e.g. with `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` and then call `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pj-assis/ppa`.

Comment: One bit thats missing form this answer is how to import the key