# add-apt-repository does not work

Tags: raspbian, apt

I am trying to install [Atom](https://atom.io/) text editor on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with Raspbian as OS.

I would like to install it via a package manager using the following commands (instructions found [here](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/10-notepad-alternatives-for-linux)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
apt-get update
apt-get install atom
```

The problem is that the `add-apt-repository` does not seem to exist on this version of Linux. I searched for it in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` and it was not there.

My questions:
* Is this normal?
* Is it possible to install the `add-apt-repository` command?
* If yes: how can I install it (or where can I find this information)?
* If no: are there any alternatives (i.e. installing a PPA repository in some other way)?

Comment: A few suggestions can be found here after a quick search... https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44622/how-to-add-ppa-entries-manually-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add ppa entries manually on Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44622/how-to-add-ppa-entries-manually-on-raspberry-pi)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In the end, the answers in the other post do help me solve my problem (i.e. install add-apt-repository). However, I feel that my question addresses the issue from a different angle, as my question was explicitly on why add-apt-repository doesn't work (the other post seems to already assume this). My understanding now is that this command simply doesn't come pre-packaged with Raspbian, but there is a way to install it. So I think it would be helpful to leave it in case someone is faced with the same issue.

Comment: I would to point to this discussion https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486841/544081 and I would to mention that this accepted way doesn't work as it should.

Just now, I'm getting the error "gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found", so it is not just simple installation. Better to avoid it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

install software-properties-common [add-apt-repository]

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Then you can start to run the standard procedure

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
```

**HOWERVER:**
it looks like there is no binary for ATOM on RASPBIAN. So at the end of the day installing ATOM this way might fail due to missing binary for RASPBIAN. I suggest to continue reading here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219192/atom-on-raspbian